# Can't Select Keystore Alias When Exporting Signed APK

Tags: android, eclipse, export, alias, keystore

I have an app that's been developed on two computers. The Keystore was created on one of the computers but I want to use that Keystore to export the signed APK on the other computer. I moved the Keystore file over with a flash drive and selected to use an existing Keystore in Eclipse. After entering the password I got the error below when I had to select the alias. It wouldn't let me select an alias so I couldn't continue with the exporting. Anyone know if Keystores can be created on one computer and used on another, or how to fix this problem?

[image: Can't select alias]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer to my own question. Apparently the keystore file I transferred over was corrupt.

Comment: Accept your own answer to mark this as answered. BTW, you don't get to see the list of aliases if the password is incorrect (or the file corrupt, naturally).

Comment: I know, Stackoverflow needs 48 hours before I can accept myself.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Thank you -so- much for the `you don't get to see the list of aliases if the password is incorrect`. I was looking all over the internet for the reason my alias list was blank, assuming my password was right. Trying another(the right) password fixed it.